I am making a 3 axis gimbal using STM32F103C8T6 blue pill, 3 MG996R servos and MPU6050 and I am currently stuck with the MPU6050 acting weird
i used two libraries from Github for I2CDev library and one other for the Mahony algorithm filter. something is wrong here and the values are really weird and they dont seem to get affected much by the orientation of the mpu6050. even after calculating the error and passing the values through mahony filter.
Dont know if i cant post links here or not but if i can please tell and i will send the links for all libraries

#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stm32f1xx.h>
#include <STM32F103Xb.h>
//#include <MadgwickAHRS.h>
#include <MahonyAHRS.h>
#include <math.h>

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

    SystemInit();
    HAL_Init();
 
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  __I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 400000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0x10;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLED;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0x11;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLED;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLED;
  HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1);

  I2Cdev_init(&hi2c1); // init of i2cdevlib.
  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  while (!MPU6050_testConnection())
  {
      MPU6050_initialize();
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      char buf[128];

      // --> enable interrupt
      MPU6050_resetSensors();   // --> Reset all sensor registers and signal paths.
      MPU6050_setIntDataReadyEnabled(1);
      MPU6050_resetAccelerometerPath();
      MPU6050_resetGyroscopePath();
      // --> CALCULATING THE ERROR FOR ACC AND GYRO

      float AccErrorX,AccErrorY,AccErrorZ =0;

      for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
          HAL_Delay(MPU6050_getAccelerometerPowerOnDelay());

              float Ax = MPU6050_getAccelerationX()/8192; // -> gravity is affecting the values
              float Ay = MPU6050_getAccelerationY()/8192;
              float Az = MPU6050_getAccelerationZ()/8192;
              AccErrorX = AccErrorX + Ax;
              AccErrorY = AccErrorY + Ay;
              AccErrorZ = AccErrorZ + Az;


      }
      AccErrorX = AccErrorX / 200;
      AccErrorY = AccErrorY / 200;
      AccErrorZ = AccErrorZ / 200;


      float GyroErrorX=0;
      float GyroErrorY=0;
      float GyroErrorZ=0;
      for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
          HAL_Delay(MPU6050_getAccelerometerPowerOnDelay());

              float Gx = MPU6050_getRotationX()/131.0;
              float Gy = MPU6050_getRotationY()/131.0;
              float Gz = MPU6050_getRotationZ()/131.0;
              GyroErrorX = GyroErrorX + (Gx / 131.0);
              GyroErrorY = GyroErrorY + (Gy / 131.0);
              GyroErrorZ = GyroErrorZ + (Gz / 131.0);

      }
      GyroErrorX = GyroErrorX / 200;
      GyroErrorY = GyroErrorY / 200;
      GyroErrorZ = GyroErrorZ / 200;


      // --> set Offset for x,y and z for accelerometer adn gyro

      MPU6050_setZAccelOffset(1551); //1551

      MPU6050_setXGyroOffset(17); //17
      MPU6050_setYGyroOffset(-69); //-69
      MPU6050_setZGyroOffset(27); //27

      HAL_Delay(100);
      MPU6050_resetSensors();
      while (1)
      {
          // --> check if data register is ready to be read

          HAL_Delay(4);

          if(MPU6050_getIntDataReadyStatus()){

              // --> Acceleration & Gyroscope values in X, Y and Z, to calculate quaternion values

              float Ax = (MPU6050_getAccelerationX()/8192); // -> gravity is affecting the values
              float Ay = (MPU6050_getAccelerationY()/8192);
              float Az = (MPU6050_getAccelerationZ()/8192)-3;

              float Gx = (MPU6050_getRotationX()/131.0)-132.198471;
              float Gy = (MPU6050_getRotationY()/131.0)+250.137405;
              float Gz = (MPU6050_getRotationZ()/131.0)-209.328247;

              // --> Get Quaternions

              MahonyAHRSupdateIMU(Gx, Gy, Gz, Ax, Ay, Az);
              float myq0 = q0;
              float myq1 = q1;
              float myq2 = q2;
              float myq3 = q3;

              // -->  Convert quaternion to Euler angles (yaw, pitch, roll)

              float yaw, pitch, roll;

              yaw = atan2(2*(myq0*myq3 + myq1*myq2), 1 - 2*(myq2*myq2 + myq3*myq3));
              pitch = asin(2*(myq0*myq2 - myq1*myq3));
              roll = atan2(2*(myq0*myq1 + myq2*myq3), 1 - 2*(myq1*myq1 + myq2*myq2));

              // --> Convert radians to degrees if necessary

              yaw *= 180.0 / M_PI;
              pitch *= 180.0 / M_PI;
              roll *= 180.0 / M_PI;

              // --> Now yaw, pitch, and roll contain the orientation angles in degrees
          }
      }
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Enables the Clock Security System
  */
  HAL_RCC_EnableCSS();
}

static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

}

static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{

}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */


i tried calculating the error for both the accelerometer and the gyroscope
succeeded with the accelerometer and managed to get the correct values for it
but as for the gyroscope it keeps acting up and the values goes up and down significantly even when the imu is stationary.

Please tell the output you are getting and the output you are expecting.

@gregspears here is some readings when on the first run when the mpu is steady :myq1 float -0.00204655924
myq2 float 4.09312279e-010
myq3 float 0.000223258583
myq0 float 0.998305202
yaw float 0.0255401917
roll float -0.00408619316
pitch float 5.24050738e-005 and here after a couple of runs after i rotated the mpu completely (turned upside down and gave it a significant tilt : myq1 float 0.0265504047
myq2 float -0.00492270291
myq3 float 0.00253306935
myq0 float 0.997943878
yaw float 0.274709195
roll float 0.0529943742
pitch float -0.570656538
